# Склонение имени собственного Ослябя

Tags: ономастика, склонение-фамилий

Согласно труду С. Платонова« Курс русской истории для гимназий» (1912), имя собственное *Ослябя* следует склонять по аналогии с нарицательным *дитя*, т.е. так: **Ослябяти, Ослябятей** и так далее. (Точную цитату не приведу: не нашла этого в учебнике, но многие сайты, начиная с Википедии, ссылаются на «Курс...») Что вы по этому поводу думаете?

Если судить чисто субъективно, склонение слова *Ослябя* по предложенному выше образцу кажется мне неблагозвучным хотя бы из-за ударения на предпоследний слог, а не на последний, как в слове *дитя*. Я привыкла к *Осляби* и так далее. Но это, конечно, не веский аргумент.

Думаю, что не лишним было бы прояснение этимологии и значения слова как имени нарицательного: здесь сайты подают разные версии. Одна из них такова: ослябя — то же самое, что и *осля*, и тогда всё логично: склоняется как *осляти* и т.д.

В общем, хотелось бы разобраться в вопросе.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ослябя •• м., стар., имя собств., сюда же – производная форма – др.-русск. отчество Аслебятевъ, 1424 г., указывающее на наличие в производящем имени основы на -ęt- (Богатова 1958, N 2).

Ослябя – из *osьl-ęb-ęt- от осёл (см.) Суфф. -ęb- известен в названиях живых существ, ср. оля́бка. Этимологический словарь Р. Фасмера 1964—1973.

Ослабити (ослаба = свободность, облегчение, льгота) — иногда значит: отпустить грехи, простить. Полный Ц-СС Дьяченко.

О склонении фамилии Ослябя: при оканчании на неударную после согласной, она изменяется по первому склонению: Кафка (роман Кафки), Окуджава (песня Окуджавы), Воля (шутка Воли).

Подробнее: [Как склонять фамилии | kakprosto.ru](https://www.kakprosto.ru/kak-10907-kak-sklonyat-familii#ixzz52wqZjce9)